# how to get data from an html form and use it to make an email with php?

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to send an email from the browser, but my PHP knowledge and experience are not enough.

So I have a html form

```
<form>
  <textarea value="Message" required></textarea>
  <input type="text" value="Name" required>
  <input type="text" value="Email" required>
  <input type="text" value="subject" required>
  <input type="reset" value="Reset" >
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My question here is how to fill this php code so I can get data from the html form and then send the email.

```
$to = "my_email@example.com";
$name =
$message = 
$from = 
$headers =
mail($to,$name,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **add an action** and a **method** (POST or GET) in your form

```
<form action="yourpage.php" method="POST">
```

After that **add a name attribute** at all your **input** :

```
<input type="text" value="Name" name="name" required>
<input type="text" value="Email" name="mail" required>
```

In **yourpage.php**

Here the method was POST so :

```
$_POST['name']; //Here get the posted value in input named 'name'
$_POST['mail'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the action in the form, and get the $_POST in PHP code, here is an example:

```
<form action="test.php">
  <textarea value="Message" required></textarea>
  <input type="text" name="Name" value="Name" required>
  <input type="text" name="Email" value="Email" required>
  <input type="text" name="subject" value="subject" required>
  <input type="reset" value="Reset" >
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

//test.php file

<?php
            $to = "my_email@example.com";
            $name = $_POST['Name'];
            $message = $_POST['Message'];
            $from = 'test@test.com';
            $headers = 'your headers';
            mail($to,$name,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: How are you going to receive this? those variables ($to,$name...) are going to be sended in the header of the email or in the message of the email?

Comment: yeah, i just copy the form and missed this, thanks :D